# Boilerplate-free Scala ArrayBuilder specialization

Tags: scala, jvm, boxing, specialization

I'm looking for good practices to avoid rewriting the same code over and over again to achieve unboxedness. Say I have something like this:

```
def speedyArrayMaker[@specialized(Long) A: ClassTag](...): Array[A] = {
  val builder = Array.newBuilder[A]
  // do stuff with builder
  builder.result
}
```

This will result in unboxed storage underlying my `builder` when possible, but as I understand it, no unboxed method calls to it because I'm going through the unspecialized `ArrayBuilder` trait.

In a monomorphic world specialized to `Long`, I'd write `val builder = new ArrayBuilder.ofLong()` and avoid boxing at all, but short of telling `ArrayBuilder`/`Builder` to be specialized on all primitive types, I can't think of a nice way to avoid duplicating effort here. One approach I've thought of might be, within `speedyArrayMaker`:

```
val (add, builder): (A => Unit, ArrayBuilder[A]) = implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass match {
  case java.lang.Long.TYPE =>
    val builder = new ArrayBuilder.ofLong()
    ((x: Long) => builder += x, builder).asInstanceOf
  case _ =>
    val builder = Array.newBuilder[A]
    ((x: A) => builder += x, builder)
}
```

Since it's only the `+=` method we really care to get specialized, and then we get a `Function1` for `add` which is specialized on `Long`. Checking with javap, indeed I get

```
90:  invokestatic    #118; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToLong:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
93:  invokeinterface #127,  2; //InterfaceMethod scala/collection/mutable/Builder.$plus$eq:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/Builder;
```

for the `Array.newBuilder[A]` version (even in the specialized output) and:

```
252: invokeinterface #204,  3; //InterfaceMethod scala/Function1.apply$mcVJ$sp:(J)V
```

for the convoluted version. I can box up this pattern into a "specialized builder helper" function, but it feels ugly especially when it's still dispatching at runtime based on something known at compile time during specialization. Ultimately I'd say my proposal here is to piggyback on the fact that `Function1` is already specialized, and I don't particularly like it.

Are there clever tricks I can use to make this more pleasant? I realize this is a really low-level detail and will rarely be performance-critical, but given the amount of effort/code duplication that went into all the `ArrayBuilder.of*` specialized classes, it seems a pity to throw away some of their advantages in exchange for being polymorphic.

**Edit**
I thought of something ugly but that I was hoping would work:

```
def builderOf(x: Array[Int]): ArrayBuilder.ofInt = new ArrayBuilder.ofInt()
def builderOf(x: Array[Long]): ArrayBuilder.ofLong = new ArrayBuilder.ofLong()
def builderOf[A: ClassTag](x: Array[A]): ArrayBuilder[A] = ArrayBuilder.make[A]
```

and then inside my specialized function:

```
val witness: Array[A] = null
val builder = builderOf(witness)
```

but it seems to call the generic `builderOf` even in the specialized version (even though enough type information is available to call the `Array[Long]` version). Anyone know why this doesn't work? The approach seems fairly clean, compared to the other one I was proposing. I guess I was hoping for a more "macro-like" approach to specialization, but I guess there's no guarantee that it'll be type-correct for all instantiations unless it picks the same method for each specialization :(

Comment: I am not sure to see how anything you'll do can get you any specialization, given that `ArrayBuidler` is not specialized (and thus `+=` will never be specialized even if called from within a specialized method). You will only get specialization if you bypass `ArrayBuidler` altogether (by example by defining your very own specialized version).

Comment: Actually, it occured to me that specializing "just" the outer method (the one calling `+=`) might already buy us a significant speedup by allowing the jitter to perform monorphic cache inlining. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: My point (this is my other account) is that there are a bunch of specialized `ArrayBuilder` subclasses called `ofInt`, `ofDouble`, etc. They are used when you ask for `Array.newBuilder[someprimitive]` but you can also instantiate them directly. If you use `newBuilder`, you get an `ArrayBuilder` which is not specialized, but if you instantiate a `new ArrayBuilder.ofInt()`, you will get unboxed calls to `+=` too, and that's what I was trying to capture above. You can test this by annotating the ` new ofInt()` with the more specific and less specific types and see if you get a boxing call.

Comment: Oh, got it! This was a vocabulary issue, when you said "specialized" it was clear to me that you were talking about the use of the ‛specialized‛ annotation, while in fact there are actual distinct implementations of ‛ArrayBuilder‛ (one for each element type).

Answer (score 4):

You could try something along the lines of (excuse the barbaric names),

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait SpecializedArrayBuilder[@specialized(Long) A] {
  def +=(a: A)
  def result: Array[A]
}

trait LowPrioritySpecializedArrayBuilder {
  implicit def defaultBuilder[A: ClassTag] = new SpecializedArrayBuilder[A] {
    val builder = ArrayBuilder.make[A]
    def +=(a: A) = builder += a
    def result = builder.result
  }
}

object SpecializedArrayBuilder extends LowPrioritySpecializedArrayBuilder {
  implicit val longBuilder = new SpecializedArrayBuilder[Long] {
    val builder = new ArrayBuilder.ofLong
    def +=(a: Long) = builder += a
    def result = builder.result
  }
}

object Specialized {
  def speedyArrayMaker[@specialized(Long) A](a: A)
    (implicit builder: SpecializedArrayBuilder[A]): Array[A] = {
    builder += a
    builder.result
  }

  def main(arg: Array[String]) {
    val arr = speedyArrayMaker(1L)
    println(arr)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but I guess implicits get resolved according to the specialized type, unlike overloaded methods as I was trying in the original question. I think the specific code you wrote will give me one builder instance for the entire type, but it's not hard to see how to modify it to make builders on demand.

Comment: In some sense, this is just replicating a lot of the duplication that's already in the standard library. It seems like if we wanted to start cautiously adding specialization annotations to more parts of the collections library, `ArrayBuilder` and `Builder` would be good starting points.

Comment: @MyseriousDan Yes, I concur.